# if text in div is x execute jquery for only x element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want when in a span compare this text "Free!" execute some jquery code

this is a code i used , but not work

```
<script>
    if (jQuery('span.amount:contains("Free!")')) {
    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info');
        jQuery(".amount").css("display", "none");
    }</script>
```

and this is a html

```
<span class="amount">Free!</span>
```

work but execute also when the text is not "Free!"

**UPDATE** ok the problem is other , in a page the span with class "amount compare more time in some case have a text and in other have other text"

the problem is when execute the jquery

```
jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info');
    jQuery(".amount").css("display", "none");
```

change all span with class "amount and not only with content "Free!"

so exist a method for hide and replace text for only  the span with content "Free!" in same page ?

Comment: An object is always truly in javascript

Comment: Is this what you need?: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/hy77b7j5/1/

Comment: i have found a problem, please check update

Comment: _"UPDATE ok the problem is other"_ Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: , i have a woocommerce site, i want when the price is free start the code "Query('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info');
    jQuery(".amount").css("display", "none");"   the problem is this class compare also in a bottom or in sidebar iN a carousel of other product with price different to "Free!", so when start this code hide also the price with example "45$"

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery('div.amount:contains("Free!")')` return a jQuery object. A jQuery object is always evaluate as true in a conditional statement, even if it is empty.

To know if the element exist or not, you should check the length :

```
if (jQuery('div.amount:contains("Free!")').length) { // 0 == false, else true
    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info');
    jQuery(".amount").css("display", "none");
}
```

Also note that your HTML is a `span` with the class "amount", not a `div`.

Comment: i tried this but not work "
if (jQuery('span.amount:contains("Free!")').length) { } else {
    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info');
    jQuery(".amount").css("display", "none");
}"

Answer (score 0):

use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the html value and then compare with the Text `Free!`.

This piece of code should work

```
if (jQuery('div.amount').html() == 'Free!') {
    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info');
    jQuery(".amount").css("display", "none");
}
```

You also can check each amount with [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) like this:

```
jQuery('div.amount').each(function(){
    if ($(this).html() == 'Free!') {
        jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info');
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if so you need to cache the one which contains "Free". Consider this:

```
<span class="amount">Free!</span>
<script> 
   var $free = jQuery('.amount:contains("Free")');
   if ($free.length) {
     jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info');
     $free.hide();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: the first receive this error from console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input(…)", the seconf work also when is false

Comment: this totally means you're hiding something from us.

Comment: There is no else statement in your question, and first sample tested in jsfiddle. probably your case is not yet simple as you've described.

Comment: how use jquery intested $, because with $ not work in my site

Comment: also you can do var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); But it's a long story to be told.

Comment: thanks, have solved the problem for the hide "amount" but for replace text     " jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').text('More Info')"; only when is present the text "Free!" and not in every class ".single_add_to_cart_button" ?

Comment: it's already inside of if (free.length), won't do anything if no free items found. if you need not in every case, than add an id to one of .single_add_to_cart_button's or give more context by updating your description. like if you can find a parent of free item and dive back to find addToCart button inside of that particular parent.